# Trigger event on new line in content editable div

Tags: jquery, html, css, angularjs, contenteditable

I am trying to listen for an event that indicates a new line has been created in a content editable div. The purpose is to eventually show a user some options each time a new empty line is created and the caret is on that line, or if the user clicks the caret position to a currently empty line.

In my book there seem to be four events that would lead to the user being on a new line within a contentediable div:

- pressing enter
- pasting content that has a empty new line at the end
- clicking causing the caret (blinking line) to move position to an empty line
- using the arrow keys to move to a new line

Of course in a contentediable div a new line means different things to different browsers, in chrome it seems to create `<div><br/></div>` tags, but having browsed around SO enough it seems that other browsers might create `<div><p></p></div>` or perhaps `<span>` tags.

I've now tried to figure this out a couple of times and just have to get it done. Is it really the best way to listen for new elements being added under that div, and/or check if the caret position is currently within empty 'new line' tags. checking each time the caret moves seems highly inefficient - is there a better way to do this?

To summarise for tldr; people

- is there a better way to check for new lines in content editable divs?
- how would I trigger an event based upon that efficiently?

Just fyi this is within an Angular context and I have jQuery also (the answer can choose to use or not use these libraries).

----- edit -----

So far the answers have focused on the creation of new line 'events' and monitoring those events, perhaps polling the caret position is a more reliable way to determine if the caret is on a empty line or not.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The other answers so far discussed monitoring the events that create a newline within a content editable div. However from the efforts so far it seems that this is not a reliable way to monitor if the user has brought the caret at a new line.

Despite concerns that having a setInterval event is clunky and adding to overhead, perhaps this is just my perception. I've tested the below in Firefox and Chrome on OSX.

```js
function getNewLines() {
  console.log(document.getSelection());
  if (document.getSelection().anchorNode) {
    var node = document.getSelection().anchorNode;
    var nodeContents = "";
    if (node.innerHTML) {
      nodeContents = node.innerHTML.toLowerCase();
    } else {
      nodeContents = node.innerHTML;
    }
    if (nodeContents !== undefined) {
      if (nodeContents === "" || nodeContents == "<br>" || nodeContents ==
        "<br/>" || nodeContents.substr(nodeContents.length - 5) == "<br/>" ||
        nodeContents.substr(nodeContents.length - 4) == "<br>") {
        console.log("you are on a new line :]");
      } else {
        console.log('nope not a new line');
      }
    } else {
      console.log('nice try, but no not a new line');
    }
  }
}
setInterval(getNewLines, 100);
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true">
  <p>Lets get started!</p>
</div>
```

[See Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/L68u3oq7/16/)

***side-note:*** the behaviour of newlines in content editable seems varied, but I noted in firefox that it will mimic the existing elements in the field. ie if you are using `<div></div>`, firefox will use `<div></div>`, if you are using `<p></p>` firefox will do the same

Answer (score 8):

This is what I did:

```
$("#main").keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        doSomething();
    }
});
$("#main").on("click", "div:has(br)", function () {
    doSomething();
});
$("#main").on("paste", function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        debugger;
        if ($('#main').children().last().children().last().has('br').length >0) {
            doSomething();
        }
    }, 100);
});

function doSomething(){
   alert("new line...");
}
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/egtd6d53/)

Comment: Hey @ahs works for the enter event, but not for getting to a new line via pasting content or repositioning the caret. :)

Comment: @DavidAnderton I updated the code and it now triggers when blank lines are clicked :)  But can you be more specific about what you mean by when pasting content?

Comment: By 'pasting content' I mean having the caret in the div, using `ctrl+v`, the paste option available on a right click, and also using paste option in the edit menu. The content would be `text/plain` so perhaps a few paragraphs pasted from notepad.

Comment: @DavidAnderton Haha, quite precise :P I mean, currently if I paste some lines with some blank lines inbetween, and then I click on the blank lines, you do see an alert. But that does not seem like the behaviour you expect when pasting a code, is it?

Comment: hehe so to be better at explaining: I mean if you paste and the caret ends up on a blank line the event should be triggered. ( ie however the caret ends up on a blank line, click, paste, using an arrow key, or otherwise the event is triggered )

Comment: @DavidAnderton I updated code and the JSFiddle link. If a text is pasted, and the last line is a blank line, the blank line message is triggered :)

Comment: doesnt seem to be triggering on paste and ending up on blank line for me in fiddle - everything else is good :)

Comment: @DavidAnderton are you performing any replace operation on the content text that will be paste.?

Comment: @HimeshAadeshara potentially yes, the idea for the use of the function is to have a menu appear for the user when they reach a blank line on the contenteditable

Comment: @DavidAnderton coz when you copy paste the text that always caring special characters with it like **\n**,**\t** etc within the text then at that time you need not to replace **\n** because using that with **if(selector with text .indexOf('\n')>0){ //just put your action};** thus how i thik you can achieve

Comment: @HimeshAadeshara if you have time could you send me a fiddle or post as an answer?

Comment: @DavidAnderton actually you already replaces the **\n** by <div> or something else when call comes to the **on('paste',function(){})**

Comment: @HimeshAadeshara thats right, the browser comes in a handles the paste event - in its own way ;)

Comment: @DavidAnderton are you using **moo-clientcide etc.js** ,>?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86612/discussion-between-david-anderton-and-himesh-aadeshara).

Comment: @DavidAnderton actually in office restriction area for chat so can't but if you use that kind of js than i just suggest one thing that in that js  **switch (typeOf(obj)){
  case 'string':
   return '"' + obj.replace(/[\x00-\x1f\\"]/g, escape) + '"';** from here it replaces the **\n** so for that just remove it from the array what it uses

Comment: @DavidAnderton hey David what happen yet not complited answer,.?>

Comment: @HimeshAadeshara could you give some more detail - I don't fully understand what you are saying :) I answered the question above and it's the only answer that works properly so far

Answer (score 1):

I've tested this code on Chrome and Edge.
Edge removed the empty line when I copy and pasted from notepad.

http://codepen.io/tzach/pen/XbGWjZ?editors=101

```
angular
    .module('app', [])
    .directive('contenteditable', function ($timeout) {
        return {
            link: function($scope, element, attrs) {

                element.css('white-space', 'pre');

                element.on('keypress', function (e) {
                    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
                        $timeout(function () {
                            onNewLine();
                        }, 100);
                    }
                });

                element.on('paste', function (e) {
                    $timeout(function () {
                        var text = element.text();
                        var textRows = text.split('\n');

                        var html = element.html();
                        var htmlRows = html.split('<br>');

                        if (textRows[textRows.length - 1].trim() == '' ||
                            htmlRows[htmlRows.length - 1].trim() == '') {
                                onNewLine();
                        }
                    },0);
                });

                element.on('click', function(e) {
                    var html = e.target.innerHTML;
                    var text = e.target.innerText;
                    if (text === '\n' || html.toLowerCase() === '<br>') {
                        onNewLine();
                    }
                });

                function onNewLine() {
                    alert('new empty line');
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: hey @tzach, this didnt seem to work when pasting content (including a new line) using chrome on OSX or iOS Safari. Also when using the arrow keys to navigate to a new line it is not triggered.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a start for you.  I wouldn't even bother trying to guess at different browser implementations.  Instead, shim it via pushing focus to a hidden textarea and then testing based on a newline in that (e.g. `textarea.value.match(/\n$/)`).

That should handle all use cases, and the rest is just faking caret and selection via range.  There are plugins that exist for just this purpose.

**JavaScript**

```
var contentEditable = document.querySelector('.content pre'),
    textarea = document.querySelector('.content textarea');

contentEditable.addEventListener('click', function() {
    textarea.focus();
    contentEditable.classList.add('pseudo-focus');
});
textarea.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    contentEditable.innerText = textarea.value;

    if (textarea.value.match(/\n$/)) {
        alert('newline');
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="content">
    <pre id="editable" contenteditable></pre>
    <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

## [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/5edtrb2t/)

Comment: on enter press this works, but on click it doesn't for me - also as the focus is taken off the element it seems not possible to test by moving the caret to a new line using the arrow keys. Another note is it seems to eat rich content for breakfast and turn into plain text. Using Chrome Version 44.0.2403.130 (64-bit) OSX